# jsctypes - problems using SHChangeNotifyRegister for MEDIA/DRIVE events

Tags: javascript, winapi, xul, message, jsctypes

I'm trying to use js-ctypes in Firefox to receive USB media/drive notifications, but I'm having a few issues and I can't tell if it's because I'm very inexperienced at Win32 API or awful at js-ctypes (or both!)

I've started by adapting an example I found on Alexandre Poirot's blog:

- [Blog Entry](http://blog.techno-barje.fr//post/2010/08/24/jsctypes-unleashed/)
- [Full JS Source](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/public/demo/jsctypes/example-jsctypes-full-power.txt)

That example uses js-ctypes to create a "message-only" window, and then interacts with the shell service for the purpose of communicating with the Windows notification tray.

It seems simple enough, so after some research on the merits of [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) vs [SHChangeNotifyRegister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I'm trying to adapt that (working!) example to register for device updates via `SHChangeNotifyRegister`.

The code resides in a bootstrapped (restartless) Firefox extension (code below).

The implementation of the `WindowProc` works well, as in the original example. My JavaScript callback logs the Window messages that come in (just numerically for this example).

**Problems:**

Firstly, it seems that calling `DestroyWindow` crashes Firefox (almost always) on `shutdown()` of the extension. Is there some Windows message I should handle on the "message-only" window to gracefully handle `DestryWindow` ?

Secondly, although it looks from the console output (below) that I'm getting meaningful values out of the calls to `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation` and `SHChangeNotifyRegister` (*the return values aren't errors and the `PIDLISTITEM` pointer is some real address*) I'm not getting Device/Drive messages in the JavaScript callback.

Also, I tried to reproduce the `PIDLISTITEM` structures to no avail (couldn't get `js-ctypes` to recognise them in calls to `SHChangeNotifyRegister`) and after studying some other non C++ examples, it seems that most folks are just using `long*` instead -- I hope that's the source of my misunderstanding!

I've verified via similar [C++ sample project from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the messages themselves are received when the `SHChangeNotifyRegistration` succeeds and I generate USB media events (ny inserting & removing USB flash media).

Minimal code to reproduce the issues follows:

---

**install.rdf**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
  <em:id>testwndproc@foo.com</em:id>
  <em:type>2</em:type>
  <em:name>TEST WNDPROC</em:name>
  <em:version>1.0</em:version>
  <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
  <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
  <em:description>Testing wndProc via JS-CTYPES on WIN32.</em:description>
  <em:creator>David</em:creator>

  <!-- Firefox Desktop -->
  <em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
    <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
    <em:minVersion>4.0.*</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>29.0.*</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
  </em:targetApplication>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

**bootstrap.js**:

```
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cu = Components.utils;

Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
let consoleService = Cc["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"]
                       .getService(Ci.nsIConsoleService);  
function LOG(msg) { 
    consoleService.logStringMessage("TEST-WNDPROC: "+msg); 
} 

var WindowProcType, DefWindowProc, RegisterClass, CreateWindowEx, 
    DestroyWindow, SHGetSpecialFolderLocation, WNDCLASS, wndclass, 
    messageWin, libs = {};

var windowProcJSCallback = function(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam) {
  LOG("windowProc: "+JSON.stringify([uMsg, wParam, lParam]));
  //
  // TODO: decode uMsg, wParam, lParam to interpret 
  //       the incoming ShChangeNotifyEntry messages!
  //
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
};

function startup(data, reason) {
  try {
    LOG("loading USER32.DLL ...");
    libs.user32 = ctypes.open("user32.dll");

    LOG("loading SHELL32.DLL ...");
    libs.shell32 = ctypes.open("shell32.dll");

    LOG("registering callback ctype WindowProc ...");
    WindowProc = ctypes.FunctionType(
        ctypes.stdcall_abi, ctypes.int, 
        [ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.int32_t, 
         ctypes.int32_t, ctypes.int32_t]).ptr;

    LOG("registering API CreateWindowEx ...");
    CreateWindowEx = libs.user32.declare("CreateWindowExA", 
        ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.long, 
        ctypes.char.ptr, ctypes.char.ptr, ctypes.int,
        ctypes.int, ctypes.int, ctypes.int, ctypes.int, 
        ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.voidptr_t, 
        ctypes.voidptr_t);

    LOG("registering API DestroyWindow ...");
    DestroyWindow = libs.user32.declare("DestroyWindow", 
        ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.bool, ctypes.voidptr_t);

    /*

    // previously using....

    LOG("registering ctype SHITEMID ...");
    var ShItemId = ctypes.StructType("ShItemId", [
      { cb: ctypes.unsigned_short },
      { abID: ctypes.uint8_t.array(1) }
    ]);

    LOG("registering ctype ITEMIDLIST ...");
    var ItemIDList = ctypes.StructType("ItemIDList", [
      { mkid: ShItemId }
    ]);

    */

    LOG("registering ctype SHChangeNotifyEntry ...");
    var SHChangeNotifyEntry = ctypes.StructType(
        "SHChangeNotifyEntry", [
            { pidl: ctypes.long.ptr   }, /* ItemIDList.ptr ??? */
            { fRecursive: ctypes.bool }
        ]);

    LOG("registering API SHChangeNotifyRegister ...");
    SHChangeNotifyRegister = libs.shell32.declare(
      "SHChangeNotifyRegister", ctypes.winapi_abi, 
      ctypes.unsigned_long, 
      ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.int, ctypes.long, 
      ctypes.unsigned_int,  ctypes.int, 
      SHChangeNotifyEntry.array() /* SHChangeNotifyEntry.ptr ??? */
    );

    LOG("registering ctype WNDCLASS ...");
    WNDCLASS = ctypes.StructType("WNDCLASS", [
      { style          : ctypes.uint32_t  },
      { lpfnWndProc    : WindowProc       }, 
      { cbClsExtra     : ctypes.int32_t   },
      { cbWndExtra     : ctypes.int32_t   },
      { hInstance      : ctypes.voidptr_t },
      { hIcon          : ctypes.voidptr_t },
      { hCursor        : ctypes.voidptr_t },
      { hbrBackground  : ctypes.voidptr_t },
      { lpszMenuName   : ctypes.char.ptr  },
      { lpszClassName  : ctypes.char.ptr  }
    ]);

    LOG("registering API SHGetSpecialFolderLocation ...");
    SHGetSpecialFolderLocation = libs.shell32.declare(
      "SHGetSpecialFolderLocation", ctypes.winapi_abi, 
      ctypes.long, ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.int, 
      ctypes.long.ptr        /* ItemIDList.ptr ??? */
    );

    LOG("registering API RegisterClass ...");
    RegisterClass = libs.user32.declare("RegisterClassA", 
        ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.voidptr_t, WNDCLASS.ptr);

    LOG("registering API DefWindowProc ...");
    DefWindowProc = libs.user32.declare("DefWindowProcA", 
        ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.int, ctypes.voidptr_t, 
        ctypes.int32_t, ctypes.int32_t, ctypes.int32_t);

    LOG("instatiating WNDCLASS (using windowProcJSCallback) ...");
    var cName = "class-testingmessageonlywindow";
    wndclass = WNDCLASS();
    wndclass.lpszClassName = ctypes.char.array()(cName);
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc(windowProcJSCallback);

    LOG("calling API: RegisterClass ...");
    RegisterClass(wndclass.address());

    LOG("calling API: CreateWindowEx ...");
    var HWND_MESSAGE = -3; // message-only window
    messageWin = CreateWindowEx(
      0, wndclass.lpszClassName,
      ctypes.char.array()("my-testing-window"),
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      ctypes.voidptr_t(HWND_MESSAGE), 
      null, null, null
    );

    LOG("instantiating pidl ...");
    var pidl = ctypes.long();
    LOG("Prior to call, pidl = "+pidl);

    LOG("calling API: SHGetSpecialFolderLocation ...");
    var CSIDL_DESKTOP = 0;
    var hr = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(
        messageWin, 
        CSIDL_DESKTOP, 
        pidl.address()
    );
    LOG("got back: "+hr);
    LOG("After the call, pidl = "+pidl);

    LOG("instantiating pschcne ...");
    var SHCNE = SHChangeNotifyEntry.array(1);
    var shcne = SHCNE();
    shcne[0].pidl = pidl.address();
    shcne[0].fRecursive = false;

    var WM_SHNOTIFY           = 1025;    // 0x401
    var SHCNE_DISKEVENTS      = 145439;  // 0x2381F
    var SHCNE_DRIVEADD        = 256;     // 256
    var SHCNE_DRIVEREMOVED    = 128;     // 128
    var SHCNE_MEDIAINSERTED   = 32;      // 32
    var SHCNE_MEDIAREMOVED    = 64;      // 64
    var SHCNRF_ShellLevel     = 2;       // 0x0002
    var SHCNRF_InterruptLevel = 1;       // 0x0001
    var SHCNRF_NewDelivery    = 32768;   // 0x8000

    var nSources = SHCNRF_ShellLevel | 
                   SHCNRF_InterruptLevel | 
                   SHCNRF_NewDelivery; 
    var lEvents  = SHCNE_DISKEVENTS | SHCNE_DRIVEADD | 
                   SHCNE_DRIVEREMOVED | SHCNE_MEDIAINSERTED | 
                   SHCNE_MEDIAREMOVED;
    var uMsg     = WM_SHNOTIFY;

    LOG("DEBUG: nSources="+nSources);
    LOG("DEBUG: lEvents="+lEvents);
    LOG("DEBUG: uMsg="+uMsg);

    LOG("calling API: SHChangeNotifyRegister ...");
    var reg_id = SHChangeNotifyRegister(
        messageWin, nSources, lEvents, uMsg, 1, shcne
    );
    if (reg_id > 0) {
      LOG("SUCCESS: Registered with ShellService for "+
          "DRIVE/MEDIA notifications! reg-id: "+reg_id);
    } else {
      LOG("ERROR: Couldn't register for DRIVE/MEDIA "+
          "notifications from ShellService!");
    }       

    LOG("done!");
  } catch (e) {
    LOG("ERROR: "+e);
  }
}

function shutdown(data, reason) {
  if (reason == APP_SHUTDOWN) return;
  try {

    //LOG("destroying hidden window... ");
    //DestroyWindow(messageWin);  // crash!!!

    LOG("unloading USER32.DLL ...");
    libs.user32.close();

    LOG("unloading SHELL32.DLL ...");
    libs.shell32.close();

    LOG("done!");
  } catch (e) {
    LOG("ERROR: "+e);
  }
}
```

---

**Console output:**

```
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: loading USER32.DLL ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: loading SHELL32.DLL ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering callback ctype WindowProc ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering API CreateWindowEx ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering API DestroyWindow ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering ctype SHChangeNotifyEntry ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering API SHChangeNotifyRegister ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering ctype WNDCLASS ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering API SHGetSpecialFolderLocation ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering API RegisterClass ...
17:08:25.518 TEST-WNDPROC: registering API DefWindowProc ...
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: instatiating WNDCLASS (using windowProcJSCallback) ...
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: calling API: RegisterClass ...
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: calling API: CreateWindowEx ...
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: windowProc: [36,0,2973696]
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: windowProc: [129,0,2973652]
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: windowProc: [131,0,2973728]
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: windowProc: [1,0,2973608]
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: instantiating pidl ...
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: Prior to call, pidl = ctypes.long(ctypes.Int64("0"))
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: calling API: SHGetSpecialFolderLocation ...
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: got back: 0
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: After the call, pidl = ctypes.long(ctypes.Int64("224974424"))
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: instantiating pschcne ...
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: DEBUG: [nSources=32771][lEvents=145919][uMsg=1025]
17:08:25.519 TEST-WNDPROC: calling API: SHChangeNotifyRegister ...
17:08:25.520 TEST-WNDPROC: SUCCESS: Registered with ShellService for DRIVE/MEDIA
                           notifications! reg-id: 15
17:08:25.520 TEST-WNDPROC: done!
----- &< -------
17:09:31.391 TEST-WNDPROC: unloading USER32.DLL ...
17:09:31.391 TEST-WNDPROC: unloading SHELL32.DLL ...
17:09:31.391 TEST-WNDPROC: done!
```

Comment: Are you sure FF and the shell run at the same UAC level? For example, if FF runs as admin and the explorer as limited (which is its default behavior), the two can't just communicate easily.

Comment: I am sure that both Firefox and the C++ sample run at the same UAC level; the shell user is an "Administrator" (for what that's worth). The C++ sample I linked to gets the messages. The "message-only" window I created in Firefox doesn't seem to (but I could be doing somthing wrong obviously).

Comment: The fact the shell user is an administrator is unrelated to the shell UAC level. By default in Windows, the shell (explorer.exe processes) run at limited UAC level and cannot communicate (with Windows messages) with applications ran at full UAC level.

Comment: Do you think that Firefox and the C++ sample would run at different UAC levels without my intervention? (I've just compiled and run it).

Comment: To make sure FF is at a normal level, to run it, just double click on the .exe from an explorer window. Don't try to debug it for example.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing nothing out of the ordinary to launch either Firefox nor the C++ sample. Just double-clicking the `.exe` from explorer.

Comment: @SimonMourier The code is *rather* easy to test. Just put the `.js` and `.rdf` files into a zip file with extension `.xpi`, then choose install from file from the Firefox addons interface. Could you have a look? (on windows, obviously).

Comment: It seems to be returning the same kind of messages that you get. Note a PIDL is a pointer to an variable-size, opaque, structure, not a long. See here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I'm aware of that. If you look at the code, I attempted to build that datastructure but couldn't get it to work (error values returned by SHChangeNotifyRegister). I only tried `long *` after I saw some other FFI-type examples of `SHChangeNotifyRegister` using `long*` or their `void*` equivalent (notably VB and Python), as if `SHChangeNotifyRegister` was doing a heap-allocation (I'm obviously not sure of this). I mentioned in the question that I've had trouble reproducing the `PIDLISTITEM` datastructure with `js-ctypes` -- can you see what I did wrong? (commented out).

Comment: I'm not familiar with cstypes as I am with PIDLISTITEM :), but I propose a change in what you did, see here: http://pastebin.com/yDYDzpX8

Comment: @SimonMourier With that change I get a zero (error) return from `SHChangeNotifyRegister`. I think that `.address()` is basically the same as `&var`, and that doing that on an existing `.ptr` type will just point to some memory that isn't itself a pointed-to-address (rather the address in memory of a pointer variable). Also, I think that I might need to allocate the structure on the heap (per the documentation you linked) and then free it afterward.

Comment: So doing `pidl: ctypes.long.ptr` is wrong Im pretty sure. Did you try doing (you probably did) `pidl: ShItemId.ptr` what was the error would it crash? If that doesnt work setting it to `ctypes.voidptr_t` is the way to go as done here: https://github.com/Noitidart/_scratchpad/blob/e5b61dda3f8c4e8554138690f5b3142a8c8d677e/IShellLink%20IPersistFile%20VTBL%20and%20COM.js#L14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking to do this, I'm posting a nasty *hack* of a work-around. (I won't accept this answer, in the hope that eventually someone will post how to do it properly).

---

After extensive reading, the only other recommended way I could of enumerating and/or determining the status of USB volumes was using WMI. The following `WQL` query did the trick:

```
select Caption, Size from win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType = 2
```

To use WQL from C++, you have to use COM. Using that from `js-ctypes` is not insignificant engineering task. You need to arrange for the DLL to be loaded and used from a `ChromeWorker` and sometimes I found that I specifically needed to make sure that JavaScript callback functions were being called from the correct Firefox thread, and that COM is not initialised in a multithreaded apartment.

`Caption` is the drive letter. It would seem that once a USB drive is ejected `Size` reports as zero.

It was then reasonably simple to call this in a polling loop inside the `ChromeWorker` thread, model the changes to the mounted volumes, and raise synthetic USB-Mounted/Ejected/Removed events in my DOM windows.

---

Unfortunately, there was one ***huge*** problem with this. If you insert a USB flash drive it generally takes between 2 and 30 seconds (depending on size) to be mounted by Windows. During that time (particularly after the 1st second or so), if you run the above `WQL` query, it will **BLOCK THE USB VOLUME FROM BEING MOUNTED BY THE OPERATING SYSTEM** (?!?) Effectively causing a denial of service.

However much incredulity this caused me, after enquiring I was assured that if I used `asynchronous` (rather than `synchronous` or `semisynchronous`) WQL queries, that the denial of service would not occur.

```
SELECT * FROM __instanceoperationevent WITHIN 2 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.DriveType = 2
```

If the `__instanceoperationevent` ISA `__InstanceCreationEvent` then the volume was added. If the `__instanceoperationevent` ISA `__InstanceDeletionEvent` then the volume was removed.

It would *seem* that when `__instanceoperationevent` ISA `__InstanceModificationEvent` then the volume was ejected, but it's not clear to me what other kind of operation could cause this. As the volume is still connected at this point, it's probably safe to deterministically query its `Size` using the first `synchronous` query (above) to check.

`asynchronous` WQL queries seem to callable in two different ways, as either `temporary` or `permanent` WMI event consumers. The difference isn't huge, but `permanent` filters+consumers seem to be recommended and don't seem to run afoul of WQL query "quotas".

Either way, there's no sane way to handle the resulting WMI events using JavaScript callbacks passed in via `js-ctypes`. :-( That left looking for a way to consume the events and then communicate them back to Firefox.

I ended up using a Strawberry perl script based on [DBD::WMI](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/DBD-WMI-0.06/lib/DBD/WMI.pm) per @Corion's answer to [a perlmonks question](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=827106) to poll asynchronously for events every 2 seconds and then used [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Socket/INET.pm) report the results to Firefox by sending them over a TCP socket. (You could do this in any language at all - I happen to be comfortable with Perl).

I then implemented `nsIServerSocket` from within my addon, waiting for `\n` terminated lines to parse the collected input and do the same modelling and synthetic events as described above.

Comment: Did you try the WQL via js-ctypes? COM is kind of fun from js-ctypes heres a guide on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Examples/Using_COM_from_js-ctypes

Comment: The problem (back when I was doing this) was that the async callback would be delivered in the wrong firefox thread (not the worker), which would crash Firefox. The examples for async WQL that I've seen use plain threading (COINIT_MULTITHREADED). It seems like the author of the article simply ignored the docs and tried Apartment threading (COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) and that worked in his case. I guess that means that it might work in my case. If I ever have a chance, I'll take another look.

Comment: Awesome! Please let me know of the work when you get to it i really enjoy seeing applications of jsctypes :)